# How to sum values in dicts if some key in that dicts has same month?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, sum

I have Django queryset:

```
summary = Contracts.objects.all() \
                   .filter(datestart__gte=time_threshold) \
                   .values('datestart', 'id_deposits__id_valuta__name') \
                   .annotate(sum=Sum('suma')) \
                   .order_by('-id_deposits__id_valuta__name')
```

And I catch qs by:

```
for s in summary:
    for k, v in CURRENCY.items():
        if s['id_deposits__id_valuta__name'] == k:
            s['sum'] *= CURRENCY[k]
```

It updates currency sum, as needed. It returns dicts

```
{'sum': Decimal('400000.00'), 'datestart': datetime.date(2016, 3, 1), 'id_deposits__id_valuta__name': 'Гривня'}
{'sum': Decimal('2500000.00'), 'datestart': datetime.date(2016, 4, 25), 'id_deposits__id_valuta__name': 'Долар'}
{'sum': Decimal('2500000.00'), 'datestart': datetime.date(2016, 4, 25), 'id_deposits__id_valuta__name': 'Долар'}
```

Now i need to sum that value of "sum" key in dicts, when months in "datestart" value are equal.

Ex. some dicts has sum, datestart keys. I need to have sum of 'sum' values when dicts has same month: 2016-04-03, 2016-04-14

So how to do this in minimalistic way?

Comment: Why not just use `for s in summary: s['sum'] *= CURRENCY.get(s['id_deposits__id_valuta__name'], 1)`? You have a dictionary here, use dictionary lookups.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I'm not so smart for oneline algorithms, sorry) and thank you for idea

Comment: So how should `2016-04-03` and `2015-04-05` be treated? Is that the same month (both April), or should they be bucketed differently (April 2016 vs April 2015)?

Comment: @MartijnPieters sould be bucketed differently,

Answer (score 2):

You can convert every dictionary to [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) where month is key and value is `s['sum']` and then add them together:

```
from collections import Counter

sum((Counter({x['datestart'].month: x['sum']}) for x in summary), Counter()) 
# Counter({4: Decimal('5000000.00'), 3: Decimal('400000.00')})
```

Note that if you need to differentiate the month and year use `{(x['datestart'].month, x['datestart'].year): x['sum']}` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary to track the sum per month; you could use a `defaultdict` here to manage initial values:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from decimal import Decimal

per_month = defaultdict(Decimal)

for s in summary:
    s['sum'] *= CURRENCY.get(s['id_deposits__id_valuta__name'], 1)
    month = s['datestart'].year, s['datestart'].month
    per_month[month] += s['sum']
```

I've removed your loop over `CURRENCY.items()`; you can just use `dict.get()` to get the value instead; if the key isn't in the dictionary, `1` is used instead.

Note that I am grouping your sums on `(year, month)` tuples, assuming that you want months in different years to be treated as separate sums.